# Flickr API - Include photo in website

Tags: flickr

Im trying to get the lastest photos uploaded by a user in my website, but im not sure how to get the URL to that resource. I can get the ID of a picture using "flickr.photosets.getPhotos", but I have no idea how to get the url for my  tag. Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a pretty simple example to do this with jquery http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Comment: take a look at this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3354211/jquery-flickr-api-issue-with-get-photo-set

Answer (score 4):

You might want to try just passing the 'extras' query parameter a value for the URL that you want to return. For example, if your request has ?extras=url_m, the photo object in the response will look like:

```
{
    "id": "8475556512",
    "secret": "beca454079",
    "server": "8102",
    "farm": 9,
    "title": "new",
    "isprimary": "0",
    "url_m": "https:\/\/farm9.staticflickr.com\/8102\/8475556512_beca454079.jpg",
    "height_m": "500",
    "width_m": "386"
}
```

Temboo has a nice interface for testing Flickr methods. You can try it out here: https://www.temboo.com/library/Library/Flickr/. They have SDKs in JAVA, Python, PHP, Ruby, Node.js, Android, and iOS.

(Full disclosure: I work at Temboo)

Answer (score 1):

You can get the tags for a given user with [flickr.tags.getListUser](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.tags.getListUser.html).  You can search by tag with [flickr.photos.search](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.search.html).

**Update**

Fill in the tag string ("horses" or "sunset" or whatever) to the tags argument to flickr.photos.search.  The [API Explorer](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/explore/flickr.photos.search) page for this endpoint is very helpful: you can fill in example arguments, query the endpoint, and see your results interactively.

**Update**

Oh, you mean the HTML tag.

See these instructions on how to [construct the URL of an image](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/misc.urls.html).

**Update**

The farm ID is available from the [flickr.photos.getInfo](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.getInfo.html) API call.  The example doesn't show it, but if you run it with the API Explorer, you'll see it.

Comment: How can I find out the farm ID?

Comment: I need to make 1 api calls to get all the photos and THEN 1 api call per each photo I want to show? That seems too complicated...

Answer (score 0):

From a tag, a call could be made by

http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=YOU-API-KEY&tags=Your-tag&api_sig=Your-API-sig

and the output is something like

```
<photo id="213636561" owner="49719616@N00" secret="55187e8a7d" server="86" farm="1" title="Hawaii Kauai I - The myth is there" ispublic="1" isfriend="0" isfamily="0" \>
```

the URL of photo is formatted as

```
http://farm{farm-id}.staticflickr.com/{server-id}/{id}_{secret}.jpg
```